# Почему при задании блоку свойства display:inline-block схлопывается изображение?

Tags: html, css, background

Если будет `display: block`, то все будет работать как надо.

```css
.block {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/8c4ZJRdy/Names-10.jpg);
  height: 700px;
  border: 40px dashed black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Но когда задается `display: inline-block`, все сжимается. Картинки вообще не видно.

```css
.block {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/8c4ZJRdy/Names-10.jpg);
  height: 700px;
  border: 40px dashed black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Разве `inline-block` без четко заданной ширины, не должен принимать ширину содержимого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Разве inline-block без четко заданной ширины, не должен принимать
> ширину содержимого?

Да, должен принимать ширину содержимого.

Но дело в том, что картинка заданная `background-image` не является содержимым блока. Чтобы она стала содержимым блока, её надо вставлять в блок тегом `<img>`.

Можно оставить и `background-image`, но тогда нужны "распорки" для блока. То есть, вставить что-нибудь в этот блок, что будет задавать ему нужную ширину.

```css
.block {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/8c4ZJRdy/Names-10.jpg);
  height: 700px;
  border: 40px dashed black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f00;
}

.block>p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p></p>
  Далее может идти любой нужный контент
</div>
```

Либо задать ширину блоку можно через `min-width`:

```css
.block {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/8c4ZJRdy/Names-10.jpg);
  height: 700px;
  border: 40px dashed black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: То есть нет такого свойства, которое бы указывало на то, что ширина блока должна быть равна ширине картинки? Как я понимаю, единственный выход из этой ситуации - это только задать блоку четкую ширину самой картинки (с учетом бордера, конечно). Как вот [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/k0a382jx/), например.

Comment: Ну там ширина и высота у блока указана. Есть вариант с тегом `<img>` как вот тут: https://jsfiddle.net/tcqws8z2/